# How do I TOTAL and display a Total for the game colums in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Below are the results of the following query

```
Select
 MOM_rebels_cms.log.AGE,
 MOM_rebels_cms.log.TEAM,
 MOM_rebels_cms.log.LAST_NAME,
 MOM_rebels_cms.log.NUMBER,
 MOM_rebels_cms.log.Game_1,
 MOM_rebels_cms.log.Game_2,
 MOM_rebels_cms.log.Game_3,
 MOM_rebels_cms.log.Game_4,
 MOM_rebels_cms.log.Game_5
From
 MOM_rebels_cms.log

id | AGE | TEAM | LAST_NAME | NUMBER | GAME_1 | GAME_2 | GAME_3 | GAME_4
 1 |  9  |Rebels|   SMITH   |   22   |    3   |    1   |    2   |    2
```

I would like to display the Total for the Game_x columns in the same row like:

```
id | AGE | TEAM | LAST_NAME | NUMBER | GAME_1 | GAME_2 | GAME_3 | GAME_4 | TOTAL
 1 |  9  |Rebels|   SMITH   |   22   |    3   |    1   |    2   |    2   |   8
```

I can get the total using:

```
 Select
  MOM_rebels_cms.log.AGE,
  MOM_rebels_cms.log.TEAM,
  MOM_rebels_cms.log.LAST_NAME,
  MOM_rebels_cms.log.NUMBER,
  MOM_rebels_cms.log.Game_1 +
  MOM_rebels_cms.log.Game_2 +
  MOM_rebels_cms.log.Game_3 +
  MOM_rebels_cms.log.Game_4
  AS TOURNEYSum
 From
  MOM_rebels_cms.log
```

but it only displays:

```
id | AGE | TEAM | LAST_NAME | NUMBER | TOTAL
 1 |  9  |Rebels|   SMITH   |   22   |   8
```

I would like to display the individual game results as well as the total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the games in a sum, but did not select them otherwise.

```
 Select
  MOM_rebels_cms.log.AGE,
  MOM_rebels_cms.log.TEAM,
  MOM_rebels_cms.log.LAST_NAME,
  MOM_rebels_cms.log.NUMBER,
  MOM_rebels_cms.log.Game_1,
  MOM_rebels_cms.log.Game_2,
  MOM_rebels_cms.log.Game_3,
  MOM_rebels_cms.log.Game_4,
  MOM_rebels_cms.log.Game_1 +
  MOM_rebels_cms.log.Game_2 +
  MOM_rebels_cms.log.Game_3 +
  MOM_rebels_cms.log.Game_4
  AS TOURNEYSum
 From
  MOM_rebels_cms.log
```

Adding the individual games to your query will work just fine.

Comment: That's great. Thank you JordanD and everyone else who chimed in. I thought I tried that but obviously I was missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the same number of games in each row, you only need to select the columns individually as well as your total:

```
Select
  MOM_rebels_cms.log.AGE,
  MOM_rebels_cms.log.TEAM,
  MOM_rebels_cms.log.LAST_NAME,
  MOM_rebels_cms.log.NUMBER,
  MOM_rebels_cms.log.Game_1,
  MOM_rebels_cms.log.Game_2,
  MOM_rebels_cms.log.Game_3,
  MOM_rebels_cms.log.Game_4,
  MOM_rebels_cms.log.Game_1 +
  MOM_rebels_cms.log.Game_2 +
  MOM_rebels_cms.log.Game_3 +
  MOM_rebels_cms.log.Game_4
  AS TOURNEYSum
 From
  MOM_rebels_cms.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select both the individual values and the sum at once. Simplifying it a little;

```
SELECT id, AGE, TEAM, LAST_NAME, NUMBER,
       Game_1,  Game_2,  Game_3,  Game_4,
       Game_1 + Game_2 + Game_3 + Game_4 AS TOTAL
FROM MOM_rebels_cms.log
```